# Maclaurin polynomial error bounds

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, rounding-error, euler-maclaurin

I need some help with my Calculus II Maclaurin polynomial error bounds.

$Mn(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ Maclaurin polynomial for $f(x) = e^x$. I need to use the error bound formula to determine a value of $n$ such that $|Mn(2) − e^2| < 10^{−4}$.

Thanks in advance for a helpful explanation of how to solve this one!

Comment: Hint: write the expansion of $e^x$, evaluate it at $x=2$, and see what the remainder needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = e^x\\
f_n(x) = 1 + x + \frac {x^2}{2} + \cdots + \frac {x^n}{n!}\\
|f_n(x) - f(x)|= \epsilon_n\\
\epsilon_n < \frac {f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x)^{n+1}$

in the interval $[0,2]$

$\epsilon_n < \frac {e^2}{(n+1)!}2^{n+1} < 10^{-4}\\
\frac {(n+1)!}{2^{n+1}}> (10^4)(e^2) = 73,891$

if $n>9$ then $f_n(2) -e^2 < 10^{-4}$

Comment: Thanks, Doug, for this very helpful explanation! I was wondering if you could clarify one more thing. I understand everything up to the point when you got the problem into the form (n+1)! / (2^(n+1)) > (10^4)(e^2) = 73,891. However, I am not sure how you estimated the final answer of n > 9. When I plug n = 9 into (n+1)! / (2^(n+1)), I get 3,543.75, which is clearly NOT greater than the number (10^4)(e^2) or 73,891. Where exactly am I missing the boat on this one? Thanks in advance for your help!